# Unknown extensions - 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: joomla-3.x, extensions

I'm using Joomla 3.9.14 Release and am no longer able to add new articles or extensions. The original installation was 3.7.x on which I recently encountered this problem.

On the main administrator page, under Maintenance, I get:

> Joomla is up to date

and

> Unknown extensions...

When I click on the latter, I get a page saying:

> An error has occurred. 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Components -> Joomla Update yields the same error.

Saving an article shows:

> Error Save failed with the following error: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

When I attempt to install a plugin, e.g. 'CookieHint', either through Web or through Package upload, I get:

> Warning
>   Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
>   Error installing plugin

When enabling Debug mode in Global Configuration, I get following trace when clicking "Unknown extensions..." again:

```
An error has occurred.
1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
E:\HostingSpaces\(USERNAMEREMOVED)\(SITENAMEREMOVED)\wwwroot\libraries\joomla\database\driver\mysqli.php:665
Call stack
#   Function    Location
1   ()  JROOT\libraries\joomla\database\driver\mysqli.php:665
2   JDatabaseDriverMysqli->execute()    JROOT\libraries\joomla\database\driver.php:1421
3   JDatabaseDriver->insertObject() JROOT\libraries\src\Table\Table.php:805
4   Joomla\CMS\Table\Table->store() JROOT\libraries\src\Updater\Updater.php:177
5   Joomla\CMS\Updater\Updater->findUpdates()   JROOT\administrator\components\com_installer\models\update.php:258
6   InstallerModelUpdate->findUpdates() JROOT\administrator\components\com_installer\controllers\update.php:102
7   InstallerControllerUpdate->find()   JROOT\libraries\src\MVC\Controller\BaseController.php:710
8   Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\BaseController->execute() JROOT\administrator\components\com_installer\installer.php:19
9   require_once()  JROOT\libraries\src\Component\ComponentHelper.php:402
10  Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::executeComponent()    JROOT\libraries\src\Component\ComponentHelper.php:377
11  Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::renderComponent() JROOT\libraries\src\Application\AdministratorApplication.php:101
12  Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->dispatch() JROOT\libraries\src\Application\AdministratorApplication.php:159
13  Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->doExecute()    JROOT\libraries\src\Application\CMSApplication.php:196
14  Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication->execute()    JROOT\administrator\index.php:51
```

What I tried:

- System -> Clear Cache & Clear Expired Cache: OK
- Update Joomla to the latest release: OK
- Extensions -> Manage -> Database -> Fix: yields `Database table structure is up to date.`
- Extensions -> Manage -> Update Sites -> Rebuild: yields `Update sites have been rebuilt from manifest files.`
- Extensions -> Languages -> Install Languages: succesfully updated to 3.9.14.1

The Joomla site that I'm using is pretty standard (few articles only, no plugins/extensions, I manually added IIRC except for a language pack).

My PHP version is 7.3.4 (on `Windows NT S057 6.3 build 9600 (Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter Edition) AMD64`). Using `protostar` as template.

Any idea what I can try next and/or how to debug further?

Comment: What PHP version? What template do you use? If you turn `development mode` on in Global configuration, is there any additional error message?

Comment: @Zollie: thanks for the pointers, added some more info.

Comment: Some table has no autoincrement on ID (maybe caused by corrupt installation or database) What the table is you can detect after enabling system debug.

Comment: @ArturStępień: I've enabled system debug (see output in my post) but it's not pointing to a certain table. How can I pinpoint?

Comment: @SaeX Table name is `#__updates`. You can try this modify query `ALTER TABLE k96qw_updates
  MODIFY update_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;` just remember to change table prefix. If that doesn't help you can change the current autoincrement value for this table in for example phpMyAdmin (set it to highest of existing values +1).

Comment: @ArturStępień: thanks, I deleted the table and re-added per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22034310/updates-table-missing-in-joomla-3. Now I no longer get the error of `Unknown extensions...`, but still cannot add a new article or install a plugin: `Save failed with the following error: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'` and `Warning Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' Error
Error installing plugin` are shown, respectively. 
Any other tables to change? How can I find out which ones?

Comment: Check every table with `#__content` or `#__categories` for lack of AUTO_INCREMENT

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I couldn't save, edit or create a new article.

The table schema for **#__ucm_history** (for some unknown reason) was not set to auto-increment the `version_id`.  The `version_id` column values started at 0 and remained 0 with every newly attempted insert.

If this is/was your situation, you could:

1. Back up your site
2. Login into your hosting account
3. Navigate to Databases
4. Select your Joomla Database
5. Look for that table  **#_ucm_history**
6. Change the **version_id** of the first entry to the highest id in the table
7. Under table **structure** click on **change** for this field **version_id**
8. Check the auto-increment option
9. Reload your site and try the failed action again.